# Save image to database and load from server

Tags: ios, iphone, image, sqlite, save

I stored images in server. Then I fetch the images and save to db1.sqlite file through image URL. Images are saved to db1.sqlite file like URL. How to display the images from saved URL. product_image having the imageURL path.

code:

sqlite table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "product" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "cat_id" INTEGER NOT NULL , "product_image" VARCHAR NOT NULL , "order_by" INTEGER NOT NULL )
```

Insert code:

```
const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into product (id, cat_id,product_image,order_by) values ('%@','%@','%@','%@')", [tuser objectForKey:@"id"], [tuser objectForKey:@"cat_id"],[tuser objectForKey:@"product_image"],[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"]] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"product insert %s", sqlInsert);

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

Image fetching:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//NSLog(@"docs dir is %@", documentsDirectory);

NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.sqlite"];
//NSLog(@"filepath %@",path);

mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_id,product_image FROM product order by order_by";

    NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    //  int catID = 0;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 2);
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 2) length:length];

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            [mArray addObject:image];

            [image release];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
else {
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    // Additional error handling, as appropriate...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chatting with you offline, I discovered that `product_image` is not a `NSData`. (I had mistakenly inferred from the presence of `sqlite3_column_blob` later, that you were trying to store binary data, which is not the case.) Apparently `product_image` is string that contains the URL. So store it as a string. And never use `stringWithFormat` in your SQL statements, but rather use the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions with `?` placeholders, e.g.:

```
const char *sqlInsert = "insert into product (id, cat_id, product_image, order_by) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 1, [[tuser objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error binding 1. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 2, [[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_id"] intValue]) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error binding 2. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [[tuser objectForKey:@"product_image"] UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error binding 3. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 4, [[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"] intValue]) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error binding 4. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

// don't forget to finalize

sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
```

---

If you do this, you have to change your code that retrieves the images, too. For example, you have:

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

    int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 2);
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 2) length:length];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    [mArray addObject:image];

    [image release];
}
```

A couple of thoughts:

1. The `[image release]` is an over-release. The `imageWithData` returns an `autorelease` object, so you don't need/want to release it. This sort of error can be catastrophic, so I'd suggest you run your code through the static analyzer to help identify these sorts of bugs (by choosing "Analyze" from the "Product" menu, or pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>). You should have *zero* warnings generated by the static analyzer. The analyzer is an incredibly useful tool to identify programming errors, so avail yourself of this excellent tool.
2. That prior point is moot, though, because you're not storing an actual image in `NSData`, but rather you're storing a URL in a string, so you should be using `sqlite3_column_text`, instead.
3. Once you convert the `const char *` you get from `sqlite3_column_text` into a `NSString`, you then want to take that string and create a URL, e.g.:

   ```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStringFromDatabase];
   ```
4. You can then use that `NSURL` in conjunction with a `UIImageView` category like [`SDWebImage`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage&ei=_E4WUvueEbXF4APEgoDgCw&usg=AFQjCNGQyP00eaYHArBWzHELyM-JVrx5uQ&bvm=bv.51156542,d.dmg), to asynchronously retrieve the image (and do all of the appropriate cacheing, etc.).

   ```
   [imageView setImageWithURL:url
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
   ```
5. And, at the risk of repeating myself, your image retrieval code checks whether the SQLite functions returned, for example `SQLITE_OK`, but if not, you're not showing the `sqlite3_errmsg`. Always look at this when debugging apps. It will save you literally hours in development/debugging.

Comment: what should i use in  "product_image" VARCHAR NOT NULL? BLOB or VarChar while creating table.

Comment: 1. Since `product_image` is a string containing the URL of the image, you should use `TEXT` for the column definition, not `BLOB`. 2. No, your image fetching code is not correct. See my revised answer.